# How to maintain script tag position on webpage?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, script-tag

I am using a script tag to add a widget to my Next.js app. I have create a section component for this widget but when I run the app it renders below my footer but it is supposed to render above as a section component. Can someone help me out with this, please?

Below you will see the screenshot of the issue, my `index.js`, the script component and the component where I hope it would be rendered.
Another user asked a [question related to the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70118835/nextjs-script-tag-how-to-maintain-position-on-webpage-see-example). Is there anyone that knows how to fix it?

[image]

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import Image from 'next/image'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.scss'
import Header from './src/components/Header'
import Services from './src/components/Services'
import Portfolio from './src/components/Portfolio'
import ContactCard from './src/components/ContactCard'
import Booking from './src/components/Booking'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <Head>
        <title>Dr Cut TheBarber Show</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />       
      </Head>
      <main className="main">
       <Header />
       <Services />
       <Portfolio />
       <ContactCard />
       <Booking />
      </main>

      <footer className="footer text-center">
        <a
          className="text-decoration-none text-dark"
          href="https://vercel.com?utm_source=create-next-app&utm_medium=default-template&utm_campaign=create-next-app"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noopener noreferrer"
        >
          Powered by{' '}
          <span className={styles.logo}>
            <Image src="/vercel.svg" alt="Vercel Logo" width={72} height={16} />
          </span>
        </a>
      </footer>
      </div>
    
  )
}
```

`Booksy.js`

```
import script from 'next/script';
//import Script from 'next/script'
import { useEffect } from 'react';
const Booksy = () =>{
    useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src="https://booksy.com/widget/code.js?id=17618&country=es&lang=es";
        script.async = true;
        document.body.appendChild(script);
        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
    }, [])
  return script
}

export default Booksy;
```

`Booking.js`

```
import Booksy from "./Booksy";

function Booking () {
    return (
        <div className="page-section">
            
                <Booksy />

        </div>
    )
}
export default Booking;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's some problem with lack of a documentation of this Booksy widget but I had the same problem and here's the solution.

This script always creating button exactly where you'll place it. So if you want to have in a specific place just create element and place script inside. Then you'll be able to change the position by positioning this element.

So in `Booking.js` add `id` for a `div` like:

```
<div id="booksy" className="page-section">
```

And modify the place where you'll mount the script like:

```
document.getElementById('booksy').appendChild(script)
```

Now you should have the Booksy button inside this `div` and you can change the position of it using styles.

Also if you want custom button for Booksy here's the trick:

1. Do like before
2. Add your custom button anywhere
3. Using styles make booksy button invisible. In SCSS this would be like:

```js
#booksy {
   .booksy-widget-container {
        display: none !important;
   }
}
```

4. Using Javascript make onClick your custom button to trigger `click()` on invisible Booksy button:

```
const openBooksy = () => {
    const button = document.querySelector(
      '#booksy > .booksy-widget-container > .booksy-widget-button'
    )
    button.click()
}
```

This will do the job.